# Surface tangent plane

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Determine a plane that is tangent to the surface $x ^{2}$ + $3y ^ 2$ + $2z ^ 2$ = $\frac{11}{6}$ and parallel to the plane x + y + z = 10

$$\nabla f (x, y, z) = (2x, 6y, 4z)$$

Quotation vector $X + Y + Z = 10 \implies (1,1,1)$

$$(2x, 6y, 4z) = K (1,1,1)$$

for $K = 1$

- $2x = 1 x = \frac{1}{2}$
- $6y = 1 y = \frac{1}{6}$
- $4z = 1 z = \frac{1}{4}$

Putting the plane equation together: $(1,1,1) [(x - 1/2) + (y-1/6) + (z-1/4)]$

My plan equation gave: $X + Y + Z = \frac{-11}{12}$

But the answer of the book is $X + Y + Z = \frac{-11}{6}$or X + Y + Z = $\frac{11}{6}$

Comment: Please see the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot impose that $K=1$. You're after a point $(x,y,z)$ of the surface $x^2+3y^2+2z^2=\frac{11}6$ which is of the form $\left(\frac K2,\frac K6,\frac K4\right)$. So, you solve the equation$$\left(\frac K2\right)^2+3\left(\frac K6\right)^2+2\left(\frac K4\right)^2=\frac{11}6.$$You will get $K=\pm2$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Could do without calculation?

Comment: I dont' think so.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error for $x$ and $y$, I obtain $K=\pm 2$ and

- $x=\pm1$
- $y=\pm \frac13$
- $z=\pm \frac12$

Comment: how did you obtain K=2? i mean it agrees with the solution, but how

Comment: @SakethMalyala You need to plug$x=K/2, y=K/6, z=K/4$ into the equation of the surface and find $K=\pm 2$.

Comment: ah, thank you. i realize that it is because this point (x,y,z) needs to be on the surface for it to be a tangent plane

Comment: @SakethMalyala Yes of course! We need that, It's really curious that you obtained a solution so near to the correct one!

Comment: I’m not sure I’d call being off by a factor of two “near.” By forcing $K=1$, the OP effectively scaled the ellipsoid by that factor of two. If the problem had started with a bigger ellipse, the scale factor would’ve been even larger.

Comment: @amd near is, because, he got the correct ratio of x,y,z but forgot to scale them so that (x,y,z) lies on the curve

Comment: @SakethMalyala Well, you did also completely miss the second solution, though to be fair the exercise you cited in your question only asked for one.

Comment: @amd this isn't my question lol